# script to check if two data frame have same data

Tags: r

I have two data frame and i want to check if the id is consistent in both data frame and if id is consistent then check if email is consistent for same id in both data frame if email, id is different then create a new data frame to show consistent and not consistent data.
at last i want to display only inconsistent data frame.

Not: sometimes email can have lower or upper case or id can also have lower or upper case.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2252","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","KTN2633","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                  city=c("del","mum","nav","pun","bang","chen","triv","vish","del","mum","bang","vish","bhop","kol","noi","gurg"),
                  email = c("akash.dev@gmail.com","rahul.singh@gmail.com",NA,NA,NA,NA,"sanu.ali@gmail.com","kunal.singh@gmail.com","lakhan.tomar@gmail.com","praveen.thakur@gmail.com","sarman.ali@gmail.com","zuber.khan@gmail.com","giriraj.singh@gmail.com","lokesh.sharma@gmail.com","pooja.pawar@gmail.com","nikita.sharma@gmail.com"),
                  Name= c("dev,akash","singh,rahul","abbas,salman","lal,ram","singh,nkunj","garg,prabal","ali,sanu","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita"))

df2 <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2152","ANA2719","ITs2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","KTN2633","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                  city=c("del","mum","nav","pun","bang","chen","ddgy","vish","del","mum","bang","vish","bhol","nhus","huay","gurg"),
                  email = c("akash.dev@gmail.com","dhumh.singh@gmail.com",NA,NA,"shoayahau",NA,"sanu.ali@gmail.com","kunal.nhil@gmail.com","lakhan.tomar@gmail.com","praveen.thakur@gmail.com","sarman.ali@gmail.com","zuber.khan@gmail.com","giriraj.singh@gmail.com","lokesh.sharma@gmail.com","pooja.pawar@gmail.com","nikita.sharma@gmail.com"),
                  Name= c("dev","singh,rahul","abbas,salman","lal,ram","singh,nkunj","huna,ghalak","khan,fhalt","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita"))
```

output should be look like

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `cols <- c("ID", "email");dplyr::anti_join(df1[cols], df2[cols])`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by="ID") %>% 
  select(ID, contains("email")) %>% 
  mutate(consistent = ifelse(email.x == email.y, "consistent", "Inconsistent")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = contains("email"), values_to = "email"
  ) %>% 
  select(ID, email, consistent) %>% 
  data.frame()
```

```
        ID                    email   consistent
1  DEV2962      akash.dev@gmail.com   consistent
2  DEV2962      akash.dev@gmail.com   consistent
3  ANA2719                     <NA>         <NA>
4  ANA2719                     <NA>         <NA>
5  DEV2698                     <NA>         <NA>
6  DEV2698                shoayahau         <NA>
7  HRT2921                     <NA>         <NA>
8  HRT2921                     <NA>         <NA>
9  KTN2633       sanu.ali@gmail.com   consistent
10 KTN2633       sanu.ali@gmail.com   consistent
11 KTN2624    kunal.singh@gmail.com Inconsistent
12 KTN2624     kunal.nhil@gmail.com Inconsistent
13 ANA2548   lakhan.tomar@gmail.com   consistent
14 ANA2548   lakhan.tomar@gmail.com   consistent
15 ITI2535 praveen.thakur@gmail.com   consistent
16 ITI2535 praveen.thakur@gmail.com   consistent
17 DEV2732     sarman.ali@gmail.com   consistent
18 DEV2732     sarman.ali@gmail.com   consistent
19 HRT2837     zuber.khan@gmail.com   consistent
20 HRT2837     zuber.khan@gmail.com   consistent
21 ERV2951  giriraj.singh@gmail.com   consistent
22 ERV2951  giriraj.singh@gmail.com   consistent
23 KTN2542  lokesh.sharma@gmail.com   consistent
24 KTN2542  lokesh.sharma@gmail.com   consistent
25 ANA2813    pooja.pawar@gmail.com   consistent
26 ANA2813    pooja.pawar@gmail.com   consistent
27 ITI2210  nikita.sharma@gmail.com   consistent
28 ITI2210  nikita.sharma@gmail.com   consistent
```